# Why does mkdir() sometimes not work?

Tags: java, multithreading, mkdir

I wrote this program to test a scenario in which `mkdir()` fails. Why is it failing?

Sometimes it works fine, and sometimes I get:

> Cannot create DIR :: myDir4
>   Cannot create DIR :: myDir4

And in the last I found every directory is created...

On every test I delete all created directoryies.

I tried this because in my project there are 100 of threads trying to test and create directories like this... and also failing the same way...

```
public class DFS {
    static long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        new Thread(new CreteDir()).start();
        new Thread(new CreteDir()).start();
        new Thread(new CreteDir()).start();
        new Thread(new CreteDir()).start();
        new Thread(new CreteDir()).start();
        new Thread(new CreteDir()).start();
        new Thread(new CreteDir()).start();
        new Thread(new CreteDir()).start();
    }
}

class CreteDir implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        //Object obj = new Object();
        synchronized (this) {
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - DFS.time1 > 10) {
            try {
                this.wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        File f1 = new File("myDir1");
        File f2 = new File("myDir2");
        File f3 = new File("myDir3");
        File f4 = new File("myDir4");
        File f5 = new File("myDir5");

        if (!f1.exists()&&!f1.mkdir()) {
            System.out.println("Cannot create DIR :: "+f1.getName());
        }
        if (!f2.exists()&&!f2.mkdir()) {
            System.out.println("Cannot create DIR :: "+f2.getName());
        }
        if (!f3.exists()&&!f3.mkdir()) {
            System.out.println("Cannot create DIR :: "+f3.getName());
        }
        if (!f4.exists()&&!f4.mkdir()) {
            System.out.println("Cannot create DIR :: "+f4.getName());
        }
        if (!f5.exists()&&!f5.mkdir()) {
            System.out.println("Cannot create DIR :: "+f5.getName());
        }
        this.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: some time i am getting message
Cannot create DIR :: myDir1
Cannot create DIR :: myDir2

I think this is due to one thread testing dir exists and got false then before mkdir operation other thread create dir... and current thread on mkdir operation getting this failure message..

Comment: Maybe that directories already exist?

Comment: @Kamil... yeah... this is just typo mistake... but for code this is no a problem...

Comment: That `synchronized (this)` doesn't make any sense. In that case `this` will be accessed only by one thread.

Comment: Running few threads at once trying to create identical dirs also doesnt make any sense...

Comment: Then how to make a perfect code... on multithreading... for this operation

Comment: In my real project there are no. of clients ... they make a request...  to store some blocks ... so i am getting no.. of requests from diff clients...

Comment: yes i wants to create only one time particular directory... but on the same time i got 100 of request....

And to solve this i put dir.exists() before dir.mkdir()

But still i'm getting that message...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a race condition.

Each thread tries to check each directory and create it if it doesn't exist yet.  What is happening is something like this:

- thread `A` tests `myDir4` and finds it doesn't exist
- thread `B` tests `myDir4` and finds it doesn't exist
- thread `A` creates `myDir4` ... success!
- thread `B` creates `myDir4` ... failure!  It already exists.

This could happen with any of the directories ... or not at all ... depending on exactly how the OS schedules the Java threads, etcetera.

---

Your code is attempting to synchronize on `this`, but the attempt is ineffective.  The `this` will be the instance of `CreteDir` that the current thread is using ... but each thread will have a different instance so there is effectively no inter-thread synchronization.  To synchronize effectively, all of the threads would need to synchronize on the same object ... but that would then render your multi-threading ineffective because the granularity is wrong.

In fact, your whole multi-threading strategy needs to be rethought.  And the fact that this is not "the real code" means that we can't really advise you on how to do that.

Reading between the lines of your last comment, I think you have three possible strategies:

- Just use a "global" lock to synchronize creation of the directories when they don't exist.  Something like this:

  ```
  // Test first without locking to reduce the concurrency bottleneck
  if (!dir.exists()) {
      synchronize (globalDirLock) {
          // Repeat the test while holding the lock
          if (!dir.exists()) { 
              if (!dir.mkdir()) {
                  System.out.println("OOOPS!");
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Create an in-memory data structure with one (lock) object per directory.  Populating that data structure needs to be done carefully to avoid a race condition where two simultaneous client requests end up creating two lock objects for a single directory.

  (If you adjust this scheme a little, you can probably also use the existence of a lock objects to avoid repeatedly checking that the directory exists.  The check involves a syscall and is non-trivial in terms of processor overheads.)
- Just ignore the cases where `File.mkdir()` returns `false`.  (Maybe do another `File.exists()` or `File.isDirectory()` test ... just in case.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding global lock, you can try this:

```
if (!f1.exists()&&!f1.mkdir()&&!f1.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Cannot create DIR :: "+f1.getName());
        }
```

`isDirectory()` will tell whether this directory is already created.